# sending a string to server in javafx does not work

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX app which reads the input of a number and then sends it to a server. The server calculates the sum of its digits and then gives the result back to the app. Im using the Task class in order to not alter the main thread of the application.

Part of the code of the app

```
calculate.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {
                String result_from_server;
                @Override
                protected String call() throws Exception {
                    try(Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",PORT);
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))){
                        warning.setText("");
                        result.setText("");
                        if(!input.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                            out.print(input.getText());
                            result_from_server = in.readLine();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return result_from_server;
                }
            };

            task.setOnSucceeded(event1 -> {
                result.setText(task.getValue());
            });
            new Thread(task).start();
        }
    });
```

The server

```
public class QuersummeServer{
static final int PORT = 4444;
public static void main(String[] args){
    try(ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        Socket cs = ss.accept();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()))){

        String number = in.readLine();
        int result = calculate(number);
        out.print(result);

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static int calculate(String number) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<number.length();i++){
        result+= Integer.valueOf(number.substring(i,i+1));
    }
    return result;
}}
```

At the end nothing happens, what is wrong?
Thanks in advance

Edit: I figured out that the server blocks after `in.readLine()` but I dont know why

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens, are you getting errors?

Comment: No errors, I figured out that the server blocks after the in.readLine() but I dont know why.

Comment: the `in.readLine()` in the server or in the client??

Comment: In the server, the client blocks after trying to read the response from the server but it never comes because of the server blocking after in.readLine()

Comment: try in the client to call the `out.flush()` method after you print the data.

Comment: mm it didnt work :/

Comment: How can you possibly know if you are getting errors? The `call` method in your task just declares it throws an exception, and you don't ever check if the task enters a `FAILED` state. Add the line `task.setOnFailed(e -> task.getException().printStackTrace());` and see if you really get an exception or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the client class after `out.print(input.getText());` to call `out.flush()`

Comment: What kind of exception you have ?

Comment: Try the method write instead a print and then flush

Comment: still no success :/

Comment: you think the client send data or the problem is when the server receive ?

Comment: Well the server does not receive nothing, but I do not know if the client is sending.. could be that the server is not receiving or the client is not sending